# Both 'minbar' and 'monajat' programs dont show up in the Unity Top Bar for Ubuntu 14.04, please help

Tags: 12.04, unity, 14.04, taskbar

I installed:(**Monojat and Minbar)**, via:

```
sudo apt-get install -y minbar monojat ; minbar & ; monojat & ;
```

When I press <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, I can see them next to the clock, but when I am in a normal workspace, they dont appear. Can anyone try to see what can be done to fix this in Ubuntu 14.04? (In Ubuntu 12~13 there was a whitelist, but these applications still dont show up next to the clock).

Any guidance? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to fix this, and wanted to post it here for others. I dont know how to do this in Ubuntu12.04 BUTTTTTTTTT for Ubuntu 14.04 I figured it out! Works perfectly:

★★★**WHITELIST INDICATOR FIX (If Icons are Dissapearing!!!)**★★★

*If your favorite apps like minbar, pidgin, skype, and monojat dont have minimized icons at the TOP systray bar... Then do this! It works!!*

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gurqn/systray-trusty sudo apt-get update ;
>   sudo apt-get upgrade sudo reboot

●○◎FYI: This is 'upgrade' this it will upgrade other things in system like Firefox●○◎

Otherwise, Thats it!